# I keep getting "FileNotFoundException" even though I handled the exception and the file does exist.

Tags: java, file, exception

```
Scanner read=new Scanner(file);
```

the exception "FileNotFoundException" occurs in this statement.

```
  import java.util.*;
  import java.io.*;

  public class shoppingList {

        public static void main(String []args)throws IOException {

              File file=new File("MyList.txt");

              try {

                   if(file.exists()==false)
                    throw new FileNotFoundException("the file input doesn't exist");
              }
              catch(FileNotFoundException e){System.out.print(e.getMessage());}

              //I tried handling the exception but it didn't work

              Scanner read=new Scanner(file);


              File outfile=new File("MyReceipt.txt");
              FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(outfile);
              PrintWriter output=new PrintWriter(fos);

              while(read.hasNext()) {
                 String item=read.next();
                 double price=read.nextDouble();
                 String status=read.next();

                 output.println("My Receipt: ");
                 output.println("--------------------");

                 if(status.equals("Done")==true)
                    output.println(item+"  "+price);


                 double total=0;


                 total+=price;
                 output.println("--------------------");
                 output.println("total= "+total);
             }

             read.close();
             output.close();
      }
 }
```

Comment: Well, the file doesn't exist where you're running the program. That's why you get the error. In order to make sure the path where your file should be, comment all the code inside `main` method and add this `new File("something.txt").createNewFile();`,run it and you will see this new file created (and the location where you should put your *MyList.txt* file).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza - that's a good idea. Alternatively, OP should try `System.out.println(new File("MyList.txt").getAbsolutePath());` to debug where program is looking for the file.

Comment: @sgp15 it won't work if *MyList.txt* file doesn't exist...

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza - `File` doesn't require a actual file to exists. Its just an abstraction unlike `FileInputStream` or `FileOutStream` that require the file to exist. I've tested it too.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the program just continues after the catch statement. So even though you handle the first FileNotFoundException that is thrown by `file.exists` you get a second one by `Scanner read=new Scanner(file);` and this one is not handled.

Answer (score 1):

After you caught the `FileNotFoundException`, you try to read another file and that throws another `FileNotFoundException`

The problem is at the line:

```
 Scanner read=new Scanner(file);
```

The solution is to put all the code in the try block:

```
File file=new File("MyList.txt");

try{

    if(file.exists()==false)
         throw new FileNotFoundException("the file input doesn't exist");

       //i tried handling the exception but it didn't work

         Scanner read;
            read = new Scanner(file);




         File outfile=new File("MyReceipt.txt");
         FileOutputStream fos;
            fos = new FileOutputStream(outfile);

         PrintWriter output=new PrintWriter(fos);

         while(read.hasNext()){
            String item=read.next();
            double price=read.nextDouble();
            String status=read.next();

            output.println("My Receipt: ");
            output.println("--------------------");

            if(status.equals("Done")==true)
               output.println(item+"  "+price);


            double total=0;


            total+=price;
            output.println("--------------------");
            output.println("total= "+total);
         }
         read.close();
         output.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Sorry to say, but that's not the solution to the problem about handling the `FileNotFoundException`, but not of the real problem (stated in the question title): *and the file does exist*. Refer to [sgp15's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15991624/1065197) to see  a possible solution.

Comment: As I understand the question, he is trying to protect the code from a     FileNotFoundException and failed.

Comment: As I understand from the question, OP needs to read the file but is getting `FileNotFoundException`, so as an alternative he/she tried to handle the exception, but that's not the solution. Read the title again: *i keep getting “FileNotFoundException” even though i handled the exception* [which is indeed a code design issue] *,and the file does exist* [which is the **real** problem]

Comment: Thas right, I keep reading doesn't insted of does. By the way, we are testing file MyList.txt and trying to read file MyReceipt.txt. Could this be the problem?

Comment: Update the page to refresh the question title. And yes, that could be a problem too.

Answer (score 1):

`new File("MyList.txt")` will try lookup the file in current directory.

Current directory depends on the environment the program is running in. For example, if the program is being run in Eclipse IDE, the Java project is current directory.

Try providing an absolute path. E.g. `C:\\workspace\\project\\MyList.txt`.

Alternatively, place the file under your source tree or a package and open an `InputStream` by classpath. For example, if its placed in a package called `my.foo.shopping` you can directly create a `Scanner` as follows.

```
Scanner read=new Scanner(shoppingList.class.getResourceAsStream("/my/foo/shoppin/MyList.txt"));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
try {

               if(file.exists()==false)
                throw new FileNotFoundException("the file input doesn't exist");
          }
          catch(FileNotFoundException e){System.out.print(e.getMessage());}

          //I tried handling the exception but it didn't work

          Scanner read=new Scanner(file);
```

the last line here shows that outside of your try-catch is where you create your `Scanner read=new Scanner(file);` the problem is, that if the file doesn't exist, there is nothing preventing the Scanner from crashing when it tries to access this file.

You should put the line `Scanner read=new Scanner(file);` inside of your try-catch, like so:

```
            try {
            if(file.exists()){
                Scanner read=new Scanner(file);
            }
            else if(file.exists()==false)
                throw new FileNotFoundException("the file input doesn't exist");
            }
        }
```

This should prevent your program from crashing if the file doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

try using the getAbsolutePath() of the file class to see to which directory you are working in and is your file present in the same directory or not. Else consider giving the full path.